# How to insert a row in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm curious if there's a way to insert a new row (that would push all the existing rows down) in an existing openpyxl worksheet?  (I'm looking to insert at the first row if it helps)

I looked through all the docs and didn't see anything mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not directly possible in openpyxl because it would require the reassigning of **all** cells below the new row.

You can do it yourself by iterating through the relevant rows (starting at the end) and writing a new row with the values of the previous row. Then you create a row of cells where you wan them.

Comment: No longer true as of [openpyxl 2.5](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html).  Use `insert_rows(idx, amount=1)`